# Given an edge, find a minimum spanning tree if exist

Tags: graph, graph-theory, theory, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I have a weighted undirected graph **G** and an edge **e**. I need to find a minimum spanning tree containing **e**, if and only if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can interpret your question 2 different ways:

1. find all minimum spanning trees. If any contains e, return it. Otherwise return null.
2. Use Kruskals algorithm, add e to the spanning tree before doing anything else. Build the remaining tree. If you are able to create a minimum spanning return it.

There are two potential points of failure:

A. the graph contains components not connected by an edge (no spanning tree exists)
 B. the minimal spanning tree does not contain e

Approach (1) fails on condition A and B. Approach (2) fails only under condition A.

Comment: For (1), you are assuming that there is only one MST, but it isn't always true. In that way, I can't be sure that the answer is correct. About (2), how can I check if the mst returner is a real mst?